# Return value closest to date between 2 tables

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I have 2 tables, both have a common ID that needs to be used to retrieve another value closest to the first table's date column.

Table_1

| ID | date_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/3/2021 |
| 2 | 4/19/2019 |
| 3 | 1/6/2020 |

Table_2

| ID | date_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/1/2021 | x |
| 1 | 4/19/2021 | y |
| 1 | 1/6/2020 | z |
| 2 | 5/19/2019 | g |
| 2 | 4/11/2019 | a |
| 3 | 4/11/2019 | bb |
| 3 | 7/17/2019 | cc |
| 3 | 1/16/2020 | dd |

And the goal is to add another column to table_1 to return the value from table_2 for the same ID that is closest to the date. In other words, I need to return the value from table_2 that shares the same ID value and has the minimum difference between date_1 and date_2.

Ex-

| ID | date_1 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/3/2021 | x |
| 2 | 4/19/2021 | a |
| 3 | 1/6/2020 | dd |

There was an `index match` result I was able to find in excel but I would like to do this in R. Unsure if `JOIN` would be the best way or there's a more iterative way to solve this.
Please help?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `dplyr` and `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate)

table_1 <- read.table(text='
ID  date_1
1   2/3/2021
2   4/19/2019
3   1/6/2020', header=T)
table_1$date_1 <- mdy(table_1$date_1)

table_2 <- read.table(text='
ID  date_2  value
1   2/1/2021    x
1   4/19/2021   y
1   1/6/2020    z
2   5/19/2019   g
2   4/11/2019   a
3   4/11/2019   bb
3   7/17/2019   cc
3   1/16/2020   dd', header=T)
table_2$date_2 <- mdy(table_2$date_2)

new_table_1 <- 
    table_2 %>% 
    left_join(table_1, by = 'ID') %>% 
    mutate(result = abs(date_2 - date_1)) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(which.min(result)) %>%
    select(ID, date_1, value)

new_table_1
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID date_1     value
  <int> <date>     <chr>
1     1 2021-02-03 x    
2     2 2019-04-19 a    
3     3 2020-01-06 dd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution. It is essential that you transform your `date` columns to `date` class before using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Table_1 %>%
  mutate(date_1 = mdy(date_1)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Min = Table_2$value[Table_2$ID == ID][which.min(abs(date_1 - Table_2$date_2[Table_2$ID == ID]))])

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
     ID date_1     Min  
  <int> <date>     <chr>
1     1 2021-02-03 x    
2     2 2019-04-19 a    
3     3 2020-01-06 dd
```

**Date**

```
Table_2
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), date_2 = structure(c(18659, 
18736, 18267, 18035, 17997, 17997, 18094, 18277), class = "Date"), 
    value = c("x", "y", "z", "g", "a", "bb", "cc", "dd")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```